# Spring Kafka 1.2.0.Relase.Jar,Spring-boot-starter 1.5.3 and spring-messaging 4.2.0

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka

I am trying to run spring-kafka intergration.I am getting below error message when I try to launch Spring boot.
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/172
As per above link,4.3 is compatible with Kafka 1.1 onwards.Has any one tried this combination.
Remember ,if you use spring-messaging (version 4.3) code won't compile and Eclipse complains 
maven config is

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependency>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>


I am trying to run below configuration to launch spring kafka.It is giving me below error when I launch SpringApplication through boot.
**Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-04-26 16:58:55.982 ERROR 10172 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.MessageMethodArgumentResolver.<init>(Lorg/springframework/messaging/converter/MessageConverter;)V
    at org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$KafkaHandlerMethodFactoryAdapter.createDefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory(KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:654) ~[spring-kafka-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$KafkaHandlerMethodFactoryAdapter.getMessageHandlerMethodFactory(KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:630) ~[spring-kafka-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$KafkaHandlerMethodFactoryAdapter.createInvocableHandlerMethod(KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:625) ~[spring-kafka-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint.configureListenerAdapter(MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint.java:112) ~[spring-kafka-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint.createMessageListener(MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint.java:101) ~[spring-kafka-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.AbstractKafkaListenerEndpoint.setupMessageListener(AbstractKafkaListenerEndpoint.java:297) ~[spring-kafka-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.AbstractKafkaListenerEndpoint.setupListenerContainer(AbstractKafkaListenerEndpoint.java:282) ~[spring-kafka-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory.createListenerContainer(AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory.java:211) ~[spring-kafka-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory.createListenerContainer(AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory.java:46) ~[spring-kafka-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.createListenerContainer(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:182) ~[spring-kafka-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.registerListenerContainer(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:154) ~[spring-kafka-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.registerListenerContainer(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:128) ~[spring-kafka-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar.registerAllEndpoints(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar.java:138) ~[spring-kafka-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar.afterPropertiesSet(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar.java:132) ~[spring-kafka-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.afterSingletonsInstantiated(KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:224) ~[spring-kafka-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:781) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at hello.Application.main(Application.java:12) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
2017-04-26 16:58:55.986  INFO 10172 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@704f3f3c: startup date [Wed Apr 26 16:58:46 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-04-26 16:58:55.990  WARN 10172 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@704f3f3c: startup date [Wed Apr 26 16:58:46 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:417) [spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1002) [spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:961) [spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:794) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:325) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at hello.Application.main(Application.java:12) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
2017-04-26 16:58:55.991  INFO 10172 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown**
```

Comment: I don't know if it's the cause, but you shouldn't override boot's Spring version from 4.3.x to 4.2.0. Boot 1.5.3 uses Spring Framework 4.3.8 - you should omit the version from the spring-messaging dependency; boot will bring in the right version.

Comment: Thanks for responding.Right version which spring boot pulls is spring-messaging-4.3.8.RELEASE.And this one does not even compile the code.ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> future=kafkaTemplate.send(topic, message);gives compilation error.Only with 4.2 it resolves the compilation issue.

Comment: Just verified that invalid LOC header (bad signature) is coming when I am trying to open the jar with decompiler.Is it something to do with download,I guess

Comment: Don't put code in comments; it's unreadable. Edit the question instead - show exactly the code that won't compile and the compiler error.

Comment: Duly noted.Issue is resolved as this was related to bad jar issue.Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

can't believe that it was bad jar issue with invalid loc header.cleaned the jar cache and it did maven build again and it resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Spring messaging removed default constructor so depending on your versions you may get the issue. Upgrade to the latest version of spring boot and messaging and the problem should be solved

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/c4fff6db1b5d35b65f01229fd057daab3bd730e2